# Android layout issue - linearlayout height not filling scrollview height

Tags: android, layout

I'm having a slight android layout issue...

I have a ScrollView element holding a LinearLayout. I want the scrollview to fill the entire device screen and the linearlayout to fill the whole height of the scrollview.

I have the code below which is resulting in the scrollView filling the whole screen but the linearLayout only filling about half of the height of the scrollview.

Here is my code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff036c07">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#FF0000"
                android:id="@+id/overview_form"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Why do you want linearlayout to fill whole screen?
It will grow according to size of scroller.
If its because of background or something, you can set it in ScrollView only

Comment: android:fillViewport="true" to the scrollview

Answer (score 16):

Add 
`android:fillViewport="true"`  
to the scrollview .

Answer (score 5):

Add the

`android:fillViewport="true"` property in your `ScrollView` 
and

also remove unncessary namespace from linearlayout which is

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 0):

try adding the weight attribute

`android:weight="1"` in linearlayout and check